# Get current time/date in purescript

Tags: purescript

This seems to me a weird question, but I have gone through the `purescript-datetime` and `purescript-js-date` and I just cannot find a way to get current `DateTime`. Is there some hidden library function or do I have to go through FFI?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `now` or `nowDateTime` functions from [`purescript-now`](https://github.com/purescript-contrib/purescript-now).